# How to develop UI which will look native to Android using jQuery-mobile?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, themeroller

I am trying to build an Android application using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. To customize UI, I am using ThemeRoller. While using ThemeRoller, I noticed that by default controls have look and feel of native iPhone controls. e.g. ON-OFF toggle switch

Is there any way to specify that the controls should have look of native Android controls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This one is called [nativeDroid](http://flypixel.com/nativedroid-a-theme-for-jquery-mobile/7892175001166318). It's new and it's true Holo, not 'Holo-like'.

I've been trying it out and I must say that it does, in fact, live up to its name, but it still has lots of issues, mainly with using icons and buttons, since this is modified jQM. Having said that, I think this is the best you or anyone else can get at the moment.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks neat... Should give it a try !!

Answer (score 4):

Another good one is [Fries](https://github.com/jaunesarmiento/fries). It's not built with jQuery Mobile but I think its better not to use jQuery mobile if you're looking for performance.

> Fries lets you create sexy Android-like UI using HTML, CSS, and
>   JavaScript.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is [onsen ui](https://onsen.io/) give it a try; it's clean and fast.